# Filtering RT (retweet) and @UserName as labels from tweet

Tags: php, regex

I am scanning tweets to see whether they are retweets or not. The retweeting convention is "RT @UserName" (as I assume we all know :-) Example:

```
$tweet = "RT @SeekingAlpha: Best Stock Bargains";
```

Whenever I come across a retweet, I try to find the original tweet in a database of tweets:

```
function _process_retweets($tweet) {
  if (substr($tweet, 0, 2) == "RT") {
    $original = preg_replace("/^RT +@[^ :]+:? */ui", "", $tweet);
    $id_str = false;
    $id_str = db_result(db_query("SELECT id_str FROM tweets WHERE text = '%s'", $original));
    $tag = ($id_str != false) ? '{RT:' . $id_str . '}' : '{RT}';
    return preg_replace("/^RT/ui", $tag, $tweet);
  }
  else {
    return $tweet;
  }
}
```

This returns:

```
{RT:3423124} @SeekingAlpha: Best Stock Bargains
```

Now, I have come across different formats, who do not place the "RT" at the beginning of the tweet:

```
$tweet = "Wow! Look at this - RT @SeekingAlpha: Best Stock Bargains";
```

Now, my function doesn't work anymore. I would scan for "RT" but then I might also see something like "am I right? rt?" as a retweet indicator. So I would have to look for the whole convention: " RT @UserName " anywhere in the tweet. What is the best way to do this, so that output would be

```
Wow! Look at this - {RT:4326565} @SeekingAlpha: Best Stock Bargains
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the "start of string" control character from your regex:

`/^RT +@[^ :]+:? */ui` becomes `/RT +@[^ :]+:?/ui`

And use preg_match to find it in the string:

```
preg_match('/RT +@[^ :]+:?/ui', $tweet, $retweets);
if (count($retweets) > 0)
{
    // we have re-tweets
}
```

Additionally, modifying the regex to be `'/RT +@[^ :]+:?(.*)/ui'` you capture the tweet name (Best Stock Bargains) into an element in the `$retweets` array.